# USB ENumeration and Suspend detect using FT232RL(USB2Serial)

Tags: usb, stm32, ftdi

I had designed a custom board with stm32l0 series controller running @32Mhz frequency. In order to Communicate used a FTDI232rl series USB to Serial Chip. As per the requirement I need to send the microcontroller to sleep mode when usb suspended mode and wake up from sleep when usb enumerated. This was implemented using voltage source from FTDI Chip connected with an voltage divider circuit.[USB Enumeration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9qm.jpg) and output from voltage divider is provided to external pin interrupt of microcontroller to find fall or rise detect on the pin. I have few issue in detecting the proper fall detect when using this circuit.

1. I have no proper detection of poper and extact fall and rise when used voltage dividor circuit.
2. Is there any proper way in which i can detect the signal interrupt for USB enumeration.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have trouble with raise and fall detection, you want to look at the signal with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Hello @TurboJ, Thanks for the reply. I have no issue in getting the interrupts but I facing problem when I enumerate the usb I have high and low signal some times 2 to 3 times. By which the interrupt occure for 2 times or sometimes 3 times. which would affect the functionality of coming out of sleep mode and going in to sleep mode.